# Align left logo

Tags: css, wordpress

this is for offtopicpolitics.com

i am trying to align the logo image i uploaded left

I am also trying to extend the nav bar all the way across the screen but have the beginning of the menu items stay the same horizontally - but black nav bar extended all the way left and right

below is a crude paint edited version of where i am trying to get them to be placed, less padding between the top and bottom logo like i have it in the picture

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1LDF.jpg)

also trying to change font color of menu items in nav bar and add one of those nav bar searches that is just a magnifying glass

thanks

edit: anyone know how to make the posts on the page grid style?

SORRY FOR THE QUESTION DUMP

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: every other question ive been in - people always ask for site link. thats why i included it. as for meaning code. what could i provide? Im asking for help coding lol

Answer (score 0):

Solution for logo and navigation bar alignment

```
#main-navigation {
    clear: none;
    float: right;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: that threw my bar up and to the right and made it 2 inches wide - lol